# Javascript - using foreach and change image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im working on a project in mvc and have a javascript to change the image on mouseover.

my problem is the follows:

the script is working but only change the image for the first li element and then when i do mouseout
it´s showing me the image of the last li element on the place of the first li.

i can´t understand what happening .

someone can give me a hand with this pls??

**here is my code:**

```
 <ul>
        @foreach (var p in ViewBag.MyIcon)
          {                               
              <li>

                  <script  type='text/javascript'>
                      function onHover() {
                          $("#iconInteraction").attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
                      }

                      function offHover() {
                          $("#iconInteraction").attr('src', '@p.Icon');
                              }
                    </script>   

                  <form action="" method="post">

                       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="Interface_Button">
               <img src="@p.Icon" onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();" id="iconInteraction"/>
               </button>                     
                  </form>
              </li>
          } 
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using id's which are causing the problem

```
                  function onHover() {
                      $(".iconInteraction").attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
                  }

                  function offHover() {
                      $(".iconInteraction").attr('src', '@p.Icon');
                          }
```

update : 
but thats not the answer the code above will just make all the iconInteraction change .

use this bit of code (put it in the head of the page.

```
$('.iconInteraction').hover(function(){
           $(this).attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
} , function(){
           $(this).attr('src', '@p.Icon');
});
```

Comment: i have try this... but now the all images change on mouseover, and on mouseout i its showing me the image of the last li element.. i have seen source and all its correct... i don´t where is failing

Comment: @user2232273 , sorry i wast paying enough attention to the question i have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which reduces the number of `<script>` tags also

```
  <script  type='text/javascript'>
      function onHover(obj) {
        $("obj").attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
      }

     function offHover(obj) {
        $("obj").attr('src', $(obj).data('original-src'));
       }
  </script>   

<ul>
    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.MyIcon)
      {                               
          <li>
              <form action="" method="post">
               <button type="submit" name="submit" id="Interface_Button">
                 <img src="@p.Icon" data-original-src="@p.Icon" 
                  onmouseover="onHover(this);" 
                  onmouseout="offHover(this);" id="iconInteraction"/>
               </button>                     
              </form>
          </li>
      } 
  </ul>
```

Comment: the image are not changing

Comment: @user2232273, which fucntion is not changing your image? place a `debugger` in that function and see what exactly you are seeing in a console

Comment: no image are changing... i have seen the output and all li have the correct information

Comment: i have solved it... take a look to my answer... and +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Youare using a duplicated `id`. This is why only the first `img` change.

Try changing the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attribute to this :

```
onHover.call(this)
offHover.call(this)
```

Then your code should be outside the `foreach` and look like this :

```
function onHover() {
      $(this).attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
}

function offHover() {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('original-src'));
}
```

Comment: @user2232273 changed my answer, the js code should be outside the foreach and use `$.data`.

Comment: i have try this... but still not working.. nothing happend.... :( .. what a headache

Comment: @user2232273 Can you make a pastebin of the final output?

Comment: i have solved it... take a look to my answer... and +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well lets make it simple. On mouse hover save the actual img-url in a custom property (actualUrl) of the same DOM object (img). On mouse leave/out restore the actual url as src.

```
 <script  type='text/javascript'>
          var onMouseOver = function(targetImg) {
            $(targetImg).attr('actualUrl', $(targetImg).prop('src'));
            $(targetImg).attr('src', '/Content/iconhover.png');
          };

         var onMouseOut = function(targetImg) {
            $(targetImg).attr('src', $(targetImg).attr('actualUrl'));
            $(targetImg).attr('actualUrl', null); // Cleaning data
         };
      </script>   

    <ul>
        @foreach (var p in ViewBag.MyIcon)
          {                               
              <li>
                  <form action="" method="post">
                   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="Interface_Button">
                     <img src="@p.Icon" onmouseover="onMouseOver(this);"
                                        onmouseout="onMouseOut(this);"/>
                   </button>                     
                  </form>
              </li>
          } 
      </ul>
```

Comment: great answer... i understand it now...but i have solved it with another way... take a look to my answer... and +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

**i have solved it..**

i have do it a little bit different but it works great.

What i have done:

i have place the call of the mouseover and mouseout in the button tag and have set a counter to create always a new id of the image tag.

i have add to the mouseover and mouseout event a `"src"`

attribute and now its working fine.

**take a look to my working code:**

hope that helps somebody else.

```
@{int x=0;} /**********Create variable and initalize with the value 0***********/

   <ul>
        @foreach (var p in ViewBag.MyIcon)
          {                               
              <li>

                  <form action="" method="post">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" onmouseover="document.getElementById('@("icon" + x.ToString())').src='/Content/hovericon.png';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('@("icon" + x.ToString())').src='@p.Icon';" >

                          <img src="@p.Icon" id="@("icon" + x.ToString())"/>

                      </button>                     
                  </form>
              </li>

              x = x + 1;   /********+1 counter********/
          } 
    </ul>
```

Comment: Writing inline JavaScript like this is not at all a good practice. Separate out the JavaScript code from your html code, use JQuery then your code will be maintainable and easy debug-able.

Comment: @Somnath... i know it and you are right... but other way its not working... i have to take a little bit of my time to make it better but its ok so... with your answer and from the other users i have to make a solution and to look how i get it to work...